# Parse two decimals from a column into two valves in sql

Tags: sql

I have an output like 9.23333 9.44444 separated by space in a column.

I want to separate that into two columns like 9.2333 in col a and 9.444 in col b

How can I do that?

Please help me

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? Also, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, mysql, postgresql, etc...).

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered? stackoverflow isn't here to do your (home)work for you, it's to answer *specific* questions about *specific* problems. So share the code (SQL in this case) you've tried so far, what inputs you're testing against, and what it's doing with those inputs vs. what you want it to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split sql string into words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875532/split-sql-string-into-words)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below query (i split my name into 2 rows), you can find my name in bold:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.e, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) value
  FROM (select **'jack chalouhy'** e) t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.e) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.e, ' ', '')))
 ORDER BY value
```

goodluck